# Keyboard code 229. Not working with preventDefault

Tags: javascript

I'm working with directives on angular and i have an input. This input should accept only numbers and a single comma. Everything looks good, but when i click the key code 229 the character is added to my input even though I validate with the following code;

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) 
onkeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
 if(event.keyCode === 229){
  event.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
event.preventDefault();
```

try using

```
killEvent(e);
```

Comment: killEvent is stopPropagation()?

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of cases, keycode `229` is not a 'real' keycode; **[it is what is sent out when the input method editor is processing key input](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html)**. After processing has finished, the **real** keycode will will triggered. Unless you are processing Scandanavian languages (where the key maps out to `å`), you don't need to worry about `229`, and should simply process the desired values instead (`0-9` and commas):

```
if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) || event.keyCode == 188) { 
  // Only accept 0-9 and commas
}
```

Comment: in macbook pro even though I'm using this check does not work.